# ASP.Net Core Identity - Join multiple Authroize-Attr

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

Is there a possibility to archive the following scenario:

I would like to give the Controller-Class a attribute like that:

[AuthGroup(„Users“)] or [AuthGroup(„Books“)]

And then give the action something like that:

[AuthType(„Read“)] or [AuthType(„Write“)]

So that i can check the combination of that?

With that example there where that 4 rights:

Users_Read
Users_Write
Books_Read
Books_Write

Any other hints for best practice are also welcome!

Comment: Policy based auth is a good way to go.
Can then mix and match roles: `services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Users", policy => policy.RequireRole("Reader"));
                options.AddPolicy("Books", policy =>
                    policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                        context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Reader") || context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Writer")));
            });`
Good article [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/c-programming/policy-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core-a-deep-dive/)

Comment: But so i have to add a policy for each object? I have much objects...
And i would like to design it that a "Reader"-Role does not habe the permission to read everything... just a view objects he has the rights for.